# Store three elements in one variable in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have the following data set and would like to store the three arrays in one variable for lookup.

```
name         date          size  
aaa          201201        0.82  
bbb          201306        1.04  
ccc          201209        0.91   
................
```

How do I store all the information in one variable? There are hundreds of rows. I am working with C#. I need to be able to search through the variable. For example, if time = 201201, name = aaa, then the size is 0.82.

Comment: Creating a custom object to store your data would make it both easy to read the code and to search the data using `LINQ`.

Comment: Either create a class containing properties representing the name, date and size, or use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) with the key as a tuple of name and date, and value as the size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: I modified my original answer to be able to search by `name` and `date` and get `size`.

You could use the `Tuple` class like this:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<string, DateTime>, float> dict = new Dictionary<Tuple<string, DateTime>, float>();
dict[new Tuple<string, DateTime>("aaa", DateTime.Now)] = 0.82f;
```

This approach assumes that the combination of `name` and `date` is unique, like an index. You can easily search by index, then.

If you need to search name/date by size, though, the wrapper class approach `Adrian Carneiro` suggested is probably better.

Comment: Should go for this solution unless you need to modify the data go with Adrian answer. `Tuple` are read only.

Comment: As a best practice, avoid exposing code that uses `Tuple` from code marked `public`. If you are using it in a single method, consider an anonymous class. `Tuple` can make your code very messy as the properties appear as `Item1`, `Item2`, etc and that is _not descriptive_. A wrapper class is always my preferred method.

Comment: Hi Thorsten Dittmar, thanks for the reply. My second column "date" is a DateTime variable. Does it work the same? Can DateTime be a key in dictionary?

Comment: I've changed the code to reflect the fact that `date` is a `DateTime`. It should work fine just the same.

Comment: Hi, I think I've got the data loaded to the Dictionary from csv file. How do I check it? I tried to use foreach(KeyValuePair.....) method but it doesn't work for the Tuple variable. Could you help further?

Comment: What do you mean *doesn't work to the Tuple variable*? You could iterate over the keys like `foreach (Tuple<string, DateTime> key in dict.Keys) ...`.

Answer (score 12):

Best way? Create a wrapper class, store in a List, query using Linq to objects:

```
public class YourStuff{
    public string Name;
    public DateTime Date;
    public double Size;
}

...

List<Stuff> myStuff = new List<Stuff>();

//then load from DataSet, DataTable, etc.
```

Some Linq examples:

```
var greaterThanOne = myStuff.Where(stuff => stuff.Size > 1);
var greaterThanOneCount = myStuff.Count(stuff => stuff.Size > 1);
var sumOfAllSizes = myStuff.Sum(stuff => stuff.Size);
```

With Linq to objects you can find, sort, slice and dice, group by, [you name it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).